# Bash script to cleanup Linux server session folder

Tags: bash, find

I'm managing a Plesk Linux webserver with multiple website-subscriptions that all run in FastCGI. The setup requires me to have a session folder for each subscription (PHP writes session data to that folder). The problem is that over time, these session folders get full and are not automatically cleared.

My hosting provider therefore created the following script, that would run weekly in a cron job.

```
#!/bin/bash

mapfile -t domains < /home/cmadmin/domains

for i in "${domains[@]}"
do
 #echo "Deleting $i Session folder content"
 find /var/www/vhosts/$i/session/* -mtime +7 -type f -delete
done
```

The objective of the script is to loop over each subscription on my server, to go into the specific session folder for that subscription and there to remove all files older than 7 days.

This script seems to work fine, but for some reason, when it reaches the subscription called `groepsmanager-rspo.com` everything inside that folder gets deleted. So even files outside the session folder, like `/var/www/hosts/groepsmanager-rspo.com/httpdocs/` and `/var/www/hosts/groepsmanager-rspo.com/logs` are deleted.

The very strange thing is that all other subscriptions are completely fine. Upon investigating their contents, indeed only files younger than 7 days remain.

At first we thought the dash (-) in the folder name might cause problems, but this is not the case, since other folder names with a dash are fine. Also, there are no files called `session` in folders outside the global session folder.

Does anyone have a clue why this particular subscription keeps getting removed? Are there any do's or dont's to keep in mind?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always quote variables and parameters; otherwise any special characters can be misinterpreted by the shell. As well, the first argument to `find` is a path; there's no need for a wildcard. If I were doing this, I'd try something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

mapfile -t domains < /home/cmadmin/domains

for i in "${domains[@]}"; do
    #echo "Deleting $i Session folder content"
    cd "/var/www/vhosts/$i/session/" || continue
    find . -mtime +7 -type f -delete
done
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Very useful. Monday I will be able to test. Please hold on, while I review your answer with my hosting partner.

Comment: I'm assuming that `/home/cmadmin/domains` is just a list with one name per line? I've never used `mapfile` before, but it seems to work fine with that sort of input. I usually just feed a `while` loop with `read`.

Comment: Hi miken32, thanks for your comments. We've tested your script and indeed, from now on only session files seem to be affected. So you solved it for us, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I bet you have mixed line-endings in the file `/home/cmadmin/domains`. I.e. all the other lines have Unix line-ending (LF) but the problematic line has Windows line-ending (CRLF). To verify this, you can run `file /home/cmadmin/domains`.

To fix it, run `dos2unix /home/cmadmin/domains`. You should still pay attention to quoting as @miken32 suggested. I warmly recommend using [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) that makes it easy to spot quoting problems.

Comment: Thanks for your remarks. Will check in detail on monday and get back to you. Very useful, thanks.

Comment: Please hold on a little bit longer. I just received word I can only test it on wednesday.

Comment: Hi jil, thanks. We've installed and used shellcheck, but it did not seem to show any encoding issues. Thanks for your viewpoints though. Very useful for the future.